# Questions about the powerseries $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}z^n,d\in\mathbb{R},z\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

The convergenceradius is $1$ that means if $|z|= 1$ then the convergencebehaviour depends on $d$.

I have several questions about this issue:

1.Why is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}$ absolutely convergent for $d>1$ and $|z|=1$

2.Why is the implication true:

series absolutely divergent $\Rightarrow$ series is divergent

3.Why is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}z^n$ divergent for $d\leq 0$  and $|z|=1$

4.Why does the convergencebehaviour depends on $z\in\{a\in\mathbb{C}||a|=1\}$ for $0<d\leq 1$?

I know that if $d$ is for example $1$ then  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}z^n$ converges absolutely for z = $-1$ and diverges for z = $1$. But the  statement above says we can go with $d$ as close to 0 as we want and we will still find a $z$ with $|z|=1$ for which  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}z^n$ converges can somebody please show me the proof for all those questions I have?

Thank you!

Comment: Not from $n=0$.

Comment: @Did Question 1-3 were answered. Can you help me with my fourth question? $\forall d\in\mathbb{R},0<d\leq1$ there exist a $|z|=1,z\neq 1$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}z^n$ converge conditionally

Comment: Please replace "there exists $|z|=1$, $z\ne1$ such that..." by "for every $|z|=1$, $z\ne1$, one has..." What did you try to solve this?

Comment: Note that $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{z^n}{n^d}=\mathrm{Li}_{d}(z)$$ where $\mathrm{Li}$ is the poly-logarithm function

Answer (score 1):

1. Apply integral test. (Thanks to T. Bongers for pointing out an error I made earlier).
2. False. $\sum \frac {(-1)^{n}} n$ is absolutely divergent but not divergent.
3. The general term does not tend to $0$ so the series is divergent.
4. For $0<d<1$ the series diverges absolutely whenever $|z|=1$. [Compare with $\sum \frac 1 n$]. The series converges for $z=-1$ and diverges for $z=1$. For $z=-1$ use Alternating Series Test.

Comment: Ratio test fails for (1). Integral test works.

Comment: Sorry in 4 I actually wanted to say $0<d\leq1$. My question was if I would take a smallpositive number in  this intervall $\epsilon$ how can I proof existence of a $z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}z^n$ converges absolutely.

Comment: @RM777 You cannot. If $d$ is a small positive number the series does not converge absolutely for any $z$ with $|z|=1$.

Comment: I  am unfammiliar with the  integral test, can I  apply also the root criteria?

Comment: @RM777 No. Root test and ratio test both fail in this case.

Comment: I know that if $d > 1$ and $|z|=1$ then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}z^n$ converges absolutely and if $0\geq d$  then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^d}z^n$ diverges. What can I say about the interval $0<d\leq 1$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You said "If d is a small positive number the series does not converge absolutely for any $z$ with $|z|=1$." Can you please explain why?

Comment: @RM777 Do  you know that the harmonic series $\sum \frac 1 n$ is divergent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87869/discussion-between-rm777-and-kavi-rama-murthy).